# Is it possible to access database.properties file from outside of project structure in Hibernate?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, servlets

I am trying to setup configuration of hibernate project with database.properties file outside of project. tried to set below in web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>propertiesLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:resources/database.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and in sdnext-servlet.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${#{contextParameters.propertiesLocation}" /> <br><br>
```

but failed to achieve required output. 
**still above configuration forces to put property file in project structure** what can be done so that it is accessible outside of project?

This below configuration is working fine for database.properties file inside project.
`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>` 
what changes need to be done so that project can access database.properties file which is outside of project.

web.xml file is

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

sdnext-servlet.xml is

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Employee</value>
                <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Books</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving an absolute path to your properties file in `location`?

Comment: @ user2004685 yes i tried like this <context:property-placeholder location="file:/location.database.properties" /> so it's working. but i am trying this so that it should not be hardcoded in either files. is it possible?

Comment: `file:${#{contextParameters.propertiesLocation}` here you are not ending `}`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @ user2004685 yes that is just editing mistake here. when i used above configuration got this: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${ (No such file or directory)

Comment: placeholders don't work instead you can try `#{environment['propertiesLocation']}`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Not working. got this:  Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driver'

Comment: Then your file isn't read (or it resolves to `null`). I also guess the EL is wrong (assumed `Environment` was exposed as a `Map` but it isn't). Try `#{environment.getRequiredProperty('propertiesLocation')}` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum when i am putting <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>  to sdnext-servlet.xml, it's working as expected. i need property file outside of project.

Comment: That will also work but for some reason you want the whole world to be configurable. Anyway read my other comment.

Comment: You can load a file from anywhere by using the `file:` prefix but for some reason you want a flexible approach instead of putting the configuration files with a well known name in a well known location. The issue is you are trying to use placeholders before you have an actual placeholder configurer, so placeholders won't work (unless it is a system or environment variable). You will have to use EL to resolve the expression (that is what I put in my other comment).

Comment: @M.Deinum: i am new to Hibernate so possibility is there if i am trying to do which is not possible. if it is not possible then please tell me

Comment: It has nothing to do with hibernate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated it has nothing to do with Hibernate or another framework besides Spring. It has to do with your misunderstanding of placeholders (processing) and [Spring EL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions).

You are trying to configure a `<context:property-placeholder />` using placeholders. Now thing about that, you are using placeholders before the infrastructure for fully parsing those placeholders is actually in place.

If you really want to use a dynamic way of setting the configuration you will have to resort to using the Spring EL. You will actually have to do *programming in xml* kind of things.

You will need to use the `environment` variable to resolve the variable from known locations, like the system environment, system properties, jndi, servlet context etc. Use the `getRequiredProperty(...)` method to resolve the value.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="#{environment.getRequiredProperty('propertiesLocation')}" />
```

**Note:** This will not work as the `location` attribute isn't aware of EL. Use a plain `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="#{environment.getRequiredProperty('propertiesLocation')}" />
</bean>
```

Now you need to define the property named `propertiesLocation` somewhere, this can be either (depending on the environment and possibilities of the environment).

- System Environment Variable
- System Property (java -D)
- Servlet Context Parameter
- Servlet Init Parameter
- JNDI

In your case you wanted to use a context param

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>propertiesLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:resources/database.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now instead of `classpath:resources/database.properties` use something else like `file:/some/path/on/your/system/database.properties`. See the reference guide on [resource loading](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-resourceloader) for more information on supported prefixes.

However you probably are better of using a System Environment variable of JNDI entry for this as else it still is quite static and you are better of directly specifying `location="file:/some/path/on/your/system/database.properties`.

Comment: thanks for effort. but after doing all the changes you mentioned, still it is not working for me.

Comment: What isn't working? If the property isn't there you should get an exception, if it does resolve to something else as `null` or `""` it should load the file. If that happens your file doesn't contain the placeholders required.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{environment.getRequiredProperty('propertiesLocation')}]

Comment: Hmm.. Apparently the `location` attribute doesn't support EL (thought it was fixed). Instead of the namespace use a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` directly instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked. i  had to change spring jars from 3.0.1 to 3.1.1

Comment: I assumed you used a more recent version 3.x isn't maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Following @user2004685 suggestion, if giving an absolute path to your properties file in `location` works, then you could surpass the *hard-coded* problem by defining a Maven property, containing the file path, that's replaced during your projects' build cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in `file:${#{contextParameters.propertiesLocation}` where you are not ending the property with `}`.

Try this:

`<context:property-placeholder location="file:#{contextParameters.propertiesLocation}"/>`

Comment: thank you for replying. but this solution is not working in my case

Comment: SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet sdnext
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /${contextParameters.propertiesLocation} (No such file or directory)