# Load properties from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to System properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, log4j, properties-file

I'm using spring 4.1.0.RELEASE and log4j 1.2.14. 
I use the next lines to load and resolve properties:

```
<bean class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="propsResolver">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
            <property name="config">
                <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
                    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
                    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="ENC_KEY" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="location" value="${properties.file}"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

In log4j configuration I have:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/path/to/myfile-${instance}.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

In `${properties.file}` I  have 'instance' property. So I run several instances of my code and want each of them to log into separate file. But I see that even when I start the 1st one it logs into `myfile-.log` without instance property value in file name. This happens because properties loaded by `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` are not loaded to System properties. How can I change it? What should I do to make placeholder configurer load properties into system.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using Maven to build and package your application?

Comment: @aribeiro , yes, I use Maven. I build executable jar and then run it like `java -jar -Dproperties.file=file:/path/to/myfile.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.xml program.jar`

Comment: You could make you of Maven's resource filtering mechanism, during your application's package goal, in order to replace the `${instance}` placeholder for the value you want. Therefore you wouldn't need the `properties` file no more.

Comment: plz check accepted answer here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173187/is-it-possible-to-access-database-properties-file-from-outside-of-project-struct/35174257#35174257]. this might help

Comment: The general problem is, that log4j loads its configuration file by its own (without spring), therefore Springs PlaceholderConfigurer will have no effect to your log4j configuration.

Comment: @Ralph, thank you. I tried to initialize log4j from spring too using: 
`<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" depends-on="propsResolver">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${log4j.file}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>`
but it still doesn't resolve property 'instance'

Comment: @aribeiro, this is not the option for me. As I said in comment above I provide property in runtime

Comment: @Vasilii Ruzov: sorry, again: even if you start log4j with Spring (in that way), log4j will load the logfile directly, so Spring PlaceholderConfigurer is not taken in account for reading the file. -- I would recommend to register the Appender programmatic, than you can implement what ever you want and can also let Spring configure your appender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="propertyLoader" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System"/>
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <util:properties location="${myfile.properties}">
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```